# Recovering disk encryption key from TPM

Tags: data-recovery, bitlocker

I have reset my pc to factory settings but not reset TPM.

Because of this I lost access to an hdd encrypted by bitlocker on which I have important files.

Could someone suggest me a way to recover the encryption key?

PS: I have already checked on onedrive and unfortunately there is no password backup.

edit: solved

Comment: Unless you know or backed up the key or password you are out of luck unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, the entire point of a TPM is to prevent people from recovering the keys inside it while being able to use those keys (via the TPM) for encryption.

Comment: Thank you all for the input, unfortunately all I have to do is format the drive.